# Python Multi Input - Multi Output Neural Network Normalization - Inverse Results

Tags: python, neural-network

i'm trying to create a 5 input and 5 output neural network for a data prediction model. In the example below the 5 inputs are 10,8,6,4,2 and the 5 outputs are 5,4,3,2,1 and I end up with the following output after the last line is run ;
array([[0.33333334, 0.26666668, 0.19999999, 0.13333334, 0.06666668]],
      dtype=float32)

Any suggestions out there on how i can get the output array to show the values 5,4,3,2,1 which is what it was trained on ?

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x_train = np.array([[10,8,6,4,2],
                  [10,8,6,4,2],
                  [10,8,6,4,2],
                  [10,8,6,4,2],
                  [10,8,6,4,2],
                  [10,8,6,4,2],
                  [10,8,6,4,2],
                  [10,8,6,4,2],
                  [10,8,6,4,2],
                  [10,8,6,4,2]])

y_train = np.array([[5,4,3,2,1],
                  [5,4,3,2,1],
                  [5,4,3,2,1],
                  [5,4,3,2,1],
                  [5,4,3,2,1],
                  [5,4,3,2,1],
                  [5,4,3,2,1],
                  [5,4,3,2,1],
                  [5,4,3,2,1],
                  [5,4,3,2,1]])

x_test = np.array([[10,8,6,4,2],
                 [10,8,6,4,2]])

y_test = np.array([[5,4,3,2,1],
                 [5,4,3,2,1]])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=5))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=2000,batch_size=128)

model.predict(x_train[1:2], batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)
```

Comment: I think i've found my own answer here. As most of you would already know the Sequential model does not allow for multiple inputs and multiple outputs as this is taken care of by the Functional API model.

Comment: So the answer to my problem is at this [link] (https://github.com/knathanieltucker/a-bit-of-deep-learning-and-keras/blob/master/notebooks/.ipynb_checkpoints/Functional-checkpoint.ipynb). After you run line 15 the model has been fitted. I'm now stuck on how to predict new data, any suggestions for this ?